# Finch-oauth2 implicit grant

Tags: scala, rest, finagle, twitter-finagle

I've been using Finagle/Finch lately and I'm currently implementing OAuth2. The suitable grant type would be implicit, since it's a SPA (correct me if I'm wrong here). After trying to authenticate my client, it says that grant_type implicit is not a valid grant type.  After doing a bit of research and digging in the source code of Finch, I can't seem to find the implicit flow implemented.

Does anyone know if it's there and if not, what would you recommend in this situation, since the password grant is not suitable and a security risk for a SPA). Are there other OAuth2 libraries that work well with Finch and support the implicit grant?